# Putting a variable in the event log string

Tags: solidity

I have the following code in the Solidity contract:

```
event Log(string text);

uint256 public number;
```

I need to put the variable within the Log text, just like when we use backticks in Javascript:

```
`This log outputs the ${number}`
```

Is there a way to do this in Solidity?

Comment: Is it not an option for you to change the signature of the event (or add a different event)? E.g. `event LogNumber(uint256 number);`.

Comment: It is, but I'd like to listen to this event from the frontend, and receive and display it with the text, unless it's computationally more cheaper to add the text on the frontend.

Comment: It would definitely be cheaper in terms of gas to convert to text on the front end.

Comment: Thanks, and out of curiosity: is there a way to nest the events in Solidity?

Comment: I don't understand what that would mean.